# jQuery - Add classes to different amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Stackoverflow and I was wondering if someone can help me with this situation:

I want to have different blocks("**.item-wrapper**") with items("**.item**") in it. But the item inside the block needs a variable width.

Example: 
If the block contains 4 items, the items need a width of 25%. 
If the block contains 5 items, the items need a width of 20%. 
If the block contains 6 items, the items need a width of 16.66....%. 
If the block contains 7 items, the items need a width of 14.28....%.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Here do I have a JSfiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/carloc/4cjwqpf4/2/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this...CSS can do it for you.

```
   .item-wrapper {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .item-wrapper .item {
      display: table-cell;
    }
```

```css
.item-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-wrapper .item {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item-wrapper .item:nth-child(odd) {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrapper">
  <!-- 4 items -->
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
</div>

<div class="item-wrapper">
  <!-- 5 items -->
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
</div>

<div class="item-wrapper">
  <!-- 6 items -->
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
</div>

<div class="item-wrapper">
  <!-- 7 items -->
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem would be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
  $(".item-wrapper").each(function()
  {
    c = $(this).children().length;

    $(this).children().each(function(){
        $(this).css("width", (100 / c) + "%");
    }); 
  });
});
```

By looping over the all the "item-wrapper" class and then obtaining the children of the item wrapper ( by using $(this) ). Assigning them a width value based upon how many children the item-wrapper has.

With the correct calculation you can get your desired values. This case its 100% divided by the amount of children

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS as well also with Javascript:

JS Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    $( ".item-wrapper" ).each(function( index ) {
        var clen=$(this).children().length;     

            $(this).children('div').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('col'+clen);
            });         

    });      

});
```

CSS:

```
.item-wrapper {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.item-wrapper .item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    height: 50px;

}

.item-wrapper .item:nth-child(odd) {
    border-color: blue;
    color: blue;
}

.col4 { width: 25% !important; }
.col5 { width: 20% !important; }
.col6 { width: 16.6666667% !important; }
.col7 { width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714% !important; }
```

CSS class doesn't start with the number. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made this in JavaScript for you:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HydraCles/4cjwqpf4/22/)

Tested it and works. (You can test it by adding more divs.)

JavaScript:

```
 var divAmount = $('.item-wrapper > .item').length;

    if (divAmount === 4) {
        $('.item').css('width', '25%');
    } else if (divAmount === 5) {
        $('.item').css('width', '20%'); 
    } else if (divAmount === 6) {
        $('.item').css('width', '16.66%'); 
    } else if (divAmount === 7) {
        $('.item').css('width', '14.28%'); 
    };
```